# Why on earth is a "-" displaying as a question mark?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, text, encoding

- My WPF application is reading a text file and populating a listbox.
- Whenever I have text surrounded by a dash symbol i.e. "-", the line in notepad will look like this for e.g. "SAMPLE - TEXT"
- When it displays it in the application, the dash turns into a question mark !?!?!?
- I then have an Export button, which writes these back to a textfile. When that symbol is written back, in notepad it turns into a square!?!?!?
- Why on earth is this happening? Please see the screenshot

  http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9893/whatthey.png

Comment: It's a rhombus, not a triangle...

Comment: erm, thank you... not quite sure why I was calling it a triangle? lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably not a dash, it's some unicode character that looks like a dash.

Press the minus key on your keyboard and retype it.

Comment: this may be caused by editing in another computer with different regional settings, characters, etc ?

Comment: Or maybe pasting from Word or Outlook or some app that does 'smart quotes' and turns "--" into an em dash or whatnot.

Comment: Thanks la. It help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's an en dash or em dash rather than a real hyphen or minus symbol.

Typesetters will most likely try to track you down and beat you to death if they discover you're using the wrong term :-)