# What is the non-breaking character for hyphen in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, unicode

I use "\u00A0" to replace whitespaces as non-breaking spaces.
I need the same for hyphen (dash). What's the best solution for that in c#?

I Tried to add the character suggested, but "?" appears instead of "-". In debug I can see"-" during the conversion but eventually its "?".

I found out in other post that "-" which isn't an actual dash might cause "?" instead of a dash! ([Post regarding "-" and "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192804/why-on-earth-is-a-displaying-as-a-question-mark)) I need a solution for that because I need a non-breaking dash...

```
public void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (Mode == ControlMode.DesignTime)
        {
            string textToUse = string.Empty;
            string offlineScreenText = text;
            if (offlineScreenText != null)
            {
                int lblLen = Math.Min(Convert.ToInt32(_settings.MultilineLength), offlineScreenText.Length);
                textToUse = lblLen > 0 ? offlineScreenText.Substring(0, lblLen) : offlineScreenText;
            }

            _textBox.Text = textToUse;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!VerifyNumericValidity(text))
            {
                return;
            }

            _lastValue = text;

            // if there's a length limit, apply it to _lastValue 
            ApplyLengthLimit();

            if (text.Length > _textBox.MaxLength)
            {
                text = text.Substring(0, _textBox.MaxLength);
            }

            // Convertion to whitespaces in order to ignore the difference 
            // between non-breakable space ("\u00A0") and whitespaces (" ")
            string whitespacesText = text.Replace(" ", "\u00A0");
            whitespacesText = text.Replace("-", "\u2011");
            if (!whitespacesText.Equals(_textBox.Text) && !whitespacesText.Equals(_textBox.Text.TrimEnd()))
            {
                _textBox.Text = text;
            }
        }            
    }

void _textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int origCursorLocation = _textBox.SelectionStart;

        // Simple whitespeces aren't being wrapped normally, 
        // so we'll replace them with non-breakable spaces
        _textBox.Text = _textBox.Text.Replace(" ", "\u00A0");
        _textBox.Text = _textBox.Text.Replace("-", "\u2011");

        BindingLayer.RaisePresentationChanged(DependencyPropertyType.Text, _textBox.Text);

        _textBox.SelectionStart = origCursorLocation;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

This should be the hyphen you need

```
"\u2011"
```

There is a list of special characters here : http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Special_characters

Comment: Thanks! That's what I tried to do, but for some reason - this character changed to "?" in the UI :(

Comment: Can you show the relevant code - it works in my WPF textbox.

Comment: Code added above. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what _BindingLayer.RaisePresentationChanged(DependencyPropertyType.Text, _textBox.Text);_ but otherwise your code works correctly for me (no question marks, hyphens displayed as expected). One point to note is in SetText you initialise _whitespacesText_ toText with spaces replaced & then immediately overwrite that with hyphens replaced, so the spaces will be back in there - you could replace both with _        string whitespacesText = text.Replace(" ", "\u00A0").Replace("-", "\u2011");_. Have you changed fonts for the text box, otherwise I am out of ideas.

Comment: Arial font doesn't have this character. Times New Roman has. I know I'm late to the party, but was just fighting with this today :-)